# Tamaño de array leído desde teclado

Tags: c

Necesito crear un array bidimensional cuyo tamaño es leído desde teclado.

No sé cómo indicar el tamaño del array por el teclado.
Había pensado algo así, pero no va:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10
#define M 10

int main()
{
    int primo[N][M];
    int i, j;
    printf("Introduce el tamaño del array:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &primo[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos . Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Por favor, mejora la epxlicacion, por ejemplo de "pero no va". Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Yo probaría primero pidiendo por teclado el tamaño del array, guardando ese input en una variable y creando un array con los parámetros que hemos recibido por teclado

Comment: @Orz ¿ Porqué, en lugar de un comentario, no pones una respuesta ?

Comment: Es que realmente no es una respuesta, es una propuesta a ver si eso funciona, ya me ha pasado de poner comentarios así en respuesta y no están bien vistos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En C no es posible crear arrays o vectores de tamaño variable. El compilador necesita reservar el espacio de memoria para ese vector y por lo tanto el tamaño debe ser constante. Es decir:

```
const int N=10;
int primo[N];
```

Alternativamente podrías intentar reservar la memoria con `malloc`, un ejemplo de uso sería:

```
int size = 10;
char *vector;

vector = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * size);
```

Recuerda que después debes liberar la memoria que reservaste con el malloc o la aplicación tendrá pérdidas de memoria. Se evita con un `free(vector)`

Comment: Hasta C11, es perfectamente posible crear *arreglos* de tamaño variable. Desde C11, es opcional que el compilador lo soporte; de ser así (soportarlo), **no** se define la macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__`. No te confundas con C++, que es otra historia :-)